# SQLAlchemy: A table reflected from an existing table gets different table collation

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have been playing around with the SqlAlchemy example code `examples.versioned_history.history_meta` : https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/_modules/examples/versioned_history/history_meta.html.

When I use it to create history table from my existing tables, they are all created with incorrect table collation.  The existing tables are all created in Declarative as follows:

```
from history_meta import Versioned

class Thingo(Base,Versioned):
  __tablename__ = 'thingos'
  __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB', 'mysql_charset': 'utf8'}
```

Which leads to tables with a table collation property of `utf_general_ci` (good!).  When I use the example `history_meta` code to generate a `thingos_history` instance, these tables are created with a table collation property of `latin1_swedish_ci` (bad!).

What is the best way to ensure that the dynamically generated `thingos_history` table gets the same table collation property as the source table?

(If this isn't easily achieved on a per-column/per-table basis, it is acceptable for all `_history tables` to be created with UTF8 encoding)

===========================

As suggested in the comments (thanks @rfkortekaas), I have tried adding the character set (`?charset=utf8`) as a parameter to the URL query string for create_engine() as well as supplying the same as connect_args (`create_engine(uri, connect_args={'use_unicode':True,'charset':'utf8'})`), but when dynamically creating the table in the way `history_meta` does, this is ineffective and seems to be ignored in favour of MYSQL's own default collation.

As shown above, the source `thingos` table from which `thingos_history` is generated uses a Declarative table definition which specifies `'mysql_charset': 'utf8'` in the `__table_args__`, but this isn't applied to the dynamically created `thingos_history` table.  `thingos_history` doesn't have a Declarative table class definition for me to supply `__table_args__` to, it's created from the `thingos` mapper:

```
table = Table(
            local_mapper.local_table.name + "_history",
            local_mapper.local_table.metadata,
            *cols,
            schema=local_mapper.local_table.schema
        )
```

The bit I'm struggling with is what syntax does SQLAlchemy provide to setup the table collation of a table generated in this way and if there is no provision for this, what options do I have to produce a `thingos_history` table dynamically from `thingos` which *does* either use the table collation of the source table or force the table collation to `utf_general_ci`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mysql.html#create-table-arguments-including-storage-engines) the function to create a table accepts a keyword argument `mysql_charset`.

If you have a look in the `examples.versioned_history.history_meta` file on [line 127](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/9220bc9d4cd3adc3c03d0b4499bc2ffbdbeee058/examples/versioned_history/history_meta.py#L127) the history Table instance is created. You can alter this to include `mysql_charset='utf8'.

```py
table = Table(local_mapper.local_table.name + "_history",
              local_mapper.local_table.metadata,
              *cols,
              schema=local_mapper.local_table.schema,
              mysql_charset='utf8'
              )
```